# Is the 'hyper' MIDL type supported in Delphi

Tags: delphi, com, activex

Is the [`hyper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367090%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) type supported in Delphi?  If so which versions?  If not can Delphi code still use an ActiveX object that has methods and properties that use `hyper` as long as those methods/properties aren't directly called from Delphi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MIDL `hyper` is a signed, 64 bit integer. The Delphi type for this is `Int64`.

Delphi has supported 64 bit integers for as long as I can remember, certainly since Delphi 5 and probably earlier.

Comment: The Comp type is indeed old, and while not well supported I think it might have been in Delphi3. I recall fighting with it.